# Angular Testing - how do I test the code that does something depending on the activated route in a component?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to test the code that sets a page title depending on the activated route in a component.

```
//  Title Map
 pageTitleMap = {
    page1: "Page 1",
    page2: "Page 2"
  }

//  Method to be tested
 setPageTitle() {
    this._Activatedroute.url.subscribe((urlPath) => {     
      const parentPath = urlPath[0].path;
      this.pageTitle = `${this.pageTitleMap[parentPath]} - TITLE`;
    })
  }

it('should set page title depending on URL path', () => {
    //  How do I test the code in setPageTitle?
});
```

Comment: what is _Activatedroute ? Is it some custom service implemented by you or does it use ActivatedRoute from angular router?

Comment: please post complete code for unit under test.

Comment: Drenai - I will take a look at that post.  Thank you!  Cristian - _ActivatedRoute is _Activated Route: ActivatedRoute (from Angular Router)  E Maggini, I will post complete code.  thank you!